# Oracle APEX report with column count breakdown and filtering

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I am working on the following Oracle APEX v4.2.2 report. It basically requires:

1. overall employee count within all departments.
2. always the same 3 departments (A,B and C) may exist at various locations
3. every location may have the same A,B and C departments but some may just have A or A and B or all three departments.
4. employee department breakdown counts will also be required (example shown below)
5. an overall checkbox system below the report showing the user a distinct department list over all locations in the report, that will be used as a filter (example shown below)

An example report might look like this:

```
Location          Dept A.     Dept. B     Dept. C      Total Employees
----------------- ----------- ----------- ------------ ---------------
Paris             5           10          3            18
Rome              10          20          5            35
London            40          -           30           70


Filter Departments: [X]Dept. A  [X]Dept. B  []Dept. C     [Apply Filter button]
```

So using the above report example and assuming there is a database structure/connection via ids of three tables:

```
location
department
employees
```

a) I can get the overall total employee counts but what would be the best approach to also achieve employee department breakdown counts for each location department above, as shown in the report, i.e. Dept. A = 5, Dept. B = 10 and Dept. C = 3 ?

b) With the filtering feature mentioned above, if I check Dept. A and Dept. B and then press the "Apply Filter button", I need the above report to re-generate with new values based on departments checked, so new report will now look like this:

```
Location          Dept A.     Dept. B     Total Employees
----------------- ----------- ----------- ---------------
Paris             5           10          15
Rome              10          20          30
London            40          -           40
```

Comment: This is not really an Apex challenge, it's more of a SQL challenge. You need to do a bit more work - what have you come up with so far in terms of your query?

Comment: As far as the checkboxes are concerned, this is just a matter of creating a checkbox item with a list of values based on the three departments; then put display Conditions on the report columns to hide/show them depending on the value of the checkbox item.

Answer (score 1):

See my answer on [Is the following query possible with SQL Pivot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23262254/is-the-following-query-possible-with-sql-pivot)

Here is a setup you could use when your data is pivoted and the columns are dynamic. You can't escape some plsql.

### Sample tables and data:

```
CREATE TABLE DEMO_LOCATIONS ( 
  ID   NUMBER(10) 
, NAME VARCHAR2(20)
, CONSTRAINT LOCATION_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID) 
);
CREATE TABLE DEMO_DEPARTMENTS ( 
  ID          NUMBER(10)
, LOCATION_ID NUMBER(10)
, NAME        VARCHAR2(20)
, CONSTRAINT DEPARTMENT_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID)
, CONSTRAINT DEPT_LOC_FK FOREIGN KEY (LOCATION_ID) REFERENCES DEMO_LOCATIONS (ID)
);
CREATE TABLE DEMO_EMPLOYEES (
  ID            NUMBER(10)
, DEPARTMENT_ID NUMBER(10)
, NAME          VARCHAR2(20)
, CONSTRAINT EMPLOYEES_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID) 
, CONSTRAINT EMPL_DEPT_FK FOREIGN KEY (DEPARTMENT_ID) REFERENCES DEMO_DEPARTMENTS (ID)
);

DECLARE
  l_emp_id NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO demo_locations (id, name) VALUES (1, 'Paris');
  INSERT INTO demo_locations (id, name) VALUES (2, 'Rome');
  INSERT INTO demo_locations (id, name) VALUES (3, 'London');
  INSERT INTO
  INSERT INTO demo_departments(id, location_id, name) VALUES (1, 1, 'A');
  INSERT INTO demo_departments(id, location_id, name) VALUES (2, 1, 'B');
  INSERT INTO demo_departments(id, location_id, name) VALUES (3, 1, 'C');

  INSERT INTO demo_departments(id, location_id, name) VALUES (4, 2, 'A');
  INSERT INTO demo_departments(id, location_id, name) VALUES (5, 2, 'B');
  INSERT INTO demo_departments(id, location_id, name) VALUES (6, 2, 'C');

  INSERT INTO demo_departments(id, location_id, name) VALUES (7, 3, 'A');
  INSERT INTO demo_departments(id, location_id, name) VALUES (8, 3, 'B');
  INSERT INTO demo_departments(id, location_id, name) VALUES (9, 3, 'C');

  FOR I IN 1..9 LOOP
    FOR J IN 1..FLOOR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(1,10)) LOOP
      l_emp_id := l_emp_id + 1;
      INSERT INTO demo_employees (id, department_id, name) VALUES (l_emp_id, i, 'employee #'||j);
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
COMMIT;

WITH pivot_src AS (
  SELECT l.name location_name, d.name department_name, count(*) amount_employees
    FROM demo_locations l
    JOIN demo_departments d
      ON d.location_id = l.id
    JOIN demo_employees e
      ON e.department_id = d.id
   GROUP BY l.name, d.name
)
SELECT *
  FROM pivot_src
 pivot ( sum(amount_employees) as all_emps for department_name in ('A' as "Department A", 'B' as "Department B", 'C' as "Department C") );
```

### APEX

Report source:

```
DECLARE
  l_pivot_cols VARCHAR2(4000);
  l_pivot_qry VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  IF NVL(:PX_DEPTA, 'N') = 'Y' THEN
    l_pivot_cols := l_pivot_cols || '''A'' as "Department A",';
  END IF;
  IF NVL(:PX_DEPTB, 'N') = 'Y' THEN
    l_pivot_cols := l_pivot_cols || '''B'' as "Department B",';
  END IF;
  IF NVL(:PX_DEPTC, 'N') = 'Y' THEN
    l_pivot_cols := l_pivot_cols || '''C'' as "Department C",';
  END IF;

  l_pivot_cols := RTRIM(l_pivot_cols, ',');

  l_pivot_qry := 
   ' WITH pivot_src AS ( '
|| '   SELECT l.name location_name, d.name department_name, count(*) amount_employees '
|| '     FROM demo_locations l '
|| '     JOIN demo_departments d '
|| '       ON d.location_id = l.id '
|| '     JOIN demo_employees e '
|| '       ON e.department_id = d.id '
|| '    GROUP BY l.name, d.name '
|| ' ) '
|| ' SELECT * '
|| '   FROM pivot_src '
|| '  pivot ( sum(amount_employees) as all_emps for department_name in ('||l_pivot_cols||') ); ';

  RETURN l_pivot_qry;
END;
```

Report attributes > PLSQL Headings

```
DECLARE
  l_cols VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
  l_cols := 'Location:';

  IF :PX_DEPTA = 'Y' THEN
    l_cols := l_cols || 'Department A:';
  END IF;
  IF :PX_DEPTB = 'Y' THEN
    l_cols := l_cols || 'Department B:';
  END IF;
  IF :PX_DEPTC = 'Y' THEN
    l_cols := l_cols || 'Department C:';
  END IF;

  RETURN RTRIM(l_cols, ':');
END;
```

Make 3 checkboxes, default `Y`, LOV: `STATIC2:;Y`. Add the items to the report "Page items to submit". Create a dynamic action which fires on change of the items and which refreshes the report.

[image: what it looks like]

Answer (score 0):

For part a, it looks like a pivot table is your best bet. This is a decent article about it: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1.php

For part b, that can get tricky. You need to make sure the Dept C employees don't show up in the Total Results, and you need to hide the Dept C column.

It might be a nice user interface feature to have another checkbox to specify including all departments, and you can have a dynamic action to clear the other checkboxes when it is clicked.

To make sure the Dept C employees don't show up in the totals, you can have the following in your WHERE clause:

```
WHERE
 (
   (:PXX_DEPT_A_FILTER = 'Y' AND employee.department = 'A')
   OR 
   (:PXX_DEPT_B_FILTER = 'Y' AND employee.department = 'B')
   OR
   (:PXX_DEPT_C_FILTER = 'Y' AND employee.department = 'C')
   OR 
   :PXX_ALL_DEPTS_FILTER = 'Y'
 )
 AND
 ....
```

To hide the columns, make each column conditional on the appropriate filters being checked.

You can eliminate the use of the Filter button by using dynamic actions and Partial Page Refreshes.