# Oracle SQL: Subquery Factoring combined with PIVOT

Tags: sql, oracle11g, pivot

using subquery factoring along with `PIVOT` results in

```
ORA-56901: non-constant expression is not allowed for pivot|unpivot values
```

The question is (since this is exactly what I want to do): Is is possible to use the results of a prior query as pivot values?

I found [this ressource](https://oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1), where a inline statement is used along with XML, but I wasn't able to figure out how to get it to work (without the `XML` keyword):

```
PIVOT (SUM(quantity) AS sum FOR (product_code) IN (SELECT DISTINCT product_code 
                                                            FROM   pivot_test
                                                            WHERE  id < 10));
```

What I've got so far:

```
WITH KEYS AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT
    PARTKEY
  FROM MYKEYTABLE
)

SELECT
  *
FROM
(
  SELECT ID, PARTKEY 
  FROM MYVALUETABLE
)
PIVOT
(   
  COUNT(PARTKEY)
  FOR (PARTKEY) IN (KEYS)
);
```

Desired result should look e.g. like (which parts are used for a specific ID)

```
ID  |PARTKEY1|PARTKEY2|PARTKEY3
____|________|________|________
123 |1       |0       |1
456 |0       |1       |1
```

Comment: That resource you linked to says "Adding the XML keyword ... makes the PIVOT a little more flexible, allowing us to replace the hard coded IN clause with a subquery, or the ANY wildcard." You cannot do that for non-XML pivots. [There are dynamic workarounds](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23488207/266304) but nothing as straightforward as the XML version.

Comment: And there's no way around it? That restriction doesn't make sense to me

Comment: A query has to know how many columns will be in the result set at parse time. If the pivot is based on other data then the number of columns would vary at runtime, which isn't allowed. (The XML version always gets a single XMLType column, so that is not variable in SQL parsing terms).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation :) If you want to post that as answer I'm happy to mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF55304) says of the pivot subquery syntax:

> A subquery is used only in conjunction with the XML keyword. When you specify a subquery, all values found by the subquery are used for pivoting. The output is not the same cross-tabular format returned by non-XML pivot queries. Instead of multiple columns specified in the pivot_in_clause, the subquery produces a single XML string column.

So you cannot use a subquery with a non-XML pivot, because that would create a variable number of columns in the result set, and that is not allowed - the number of columns has to be known at parse-time. For the XML version there is always a single XMLType column so that doesn't preclude the variable IN clause you'd get from a subquery.